# How to access data inside json array

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I have below json array:

```
[
{
"ABC":{
"a1": 1
},
"Xyz": 10
},
{
"abc2": {
"b2": 10
},
"x":7
}
]
```

I am trying below code to read the values:

```
Var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log("abc:"+json[0].ABC);
```

I am getting `"json[0].ABC" undefined error`.

How do I loop this json and get the vales.
Json is generated by Gson library.

Also when I print this json string in Java after conversion I see quote before and after `[]` brackets. Is that causing any issue.

Comment: Is there an error when parsing the JSON string?

Comment: There is an extra comma after 1

Comment: There are also spaces before some of your keys, such as `" a1"`

Comment: i tried with your code, its not producing error in browser console

Comment: what is in your str?

Comment: You're also logging as a concatenated string but `json[0].ABC` is an object

Comment: Typing using mobile so few typo, I am getting undefined error. Also no error while parsing.

Comment: Why parse it? `x[0].ABC.a1` works fine ... **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1022/**

Comment: There is no such thing like a *"json array"*. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is text and nothing more. It is a text representation of some data structure. When it is parsed and the data structures are restored there is no JSON any more. In Javascript, JSON is in fact a piece of valid Javascript code, the definition of a Javascript data structure, usually an object. Yours is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need `var json = JSON.parse(str)` when your json variable is an object. What is your `str` here?

It works like this:

```
var json = [ { "ABC":{ " a1": 1, }, "Xyz": 10 }, { " abc2": { "b2": 10 }, " x":7 } ];
console.log("abc:"+json[0].ABC);
```

Result:

```
{" a1": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
 "ABC": {
  "a1": 1
 },
 "Xyz": 10
}, {
 " abc2": {
  "b2": 10
 },
 " x": 7
}]

alert(data[0].ABC);

//for better understanding, console log and check

console.log(data);
console.log(data[0].ABC);
```

Comment: It is **NOT** invalid for retrieving or inspecting attributes.

Comment: Either it is JSON and you need to parse it, or it is not JSON. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @davidkonrad, there was an extra comma before.

Comment: There is no need for parsing -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1022/** thats why it goes wrong and the result is undefined

Comment: @davidkonrad, I guess that's what I showed in my answer above.

Comment: After 3 attempts or iterations, where you started out by the opposite - yes :)